# Writing 3 expressions below \bigcup?

Tags: subscripts

Let's say I have:

```
\bigcup_{a \in X}
```

This will print a big U with `$a \in X$` below it. Now, let's say I also want to write `$b \in Y$` and `$c \in Z$`below that big U. Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). If the question @Werner linked to does not resolve your issue please let us know. Otherwise this question will get closed as a duplicate.